Draft.js highlight mention text
668 / 5.000
I'm having some issues trying to use draft-js to create a mention user functionality. I want to show a suggestion list (called from the API when typing @, and when scrolling in that list, it will infinite scroll to call more), when selecting a user, it will be mentioned and the text will be colored blue. Currently with this code, I can only mention the user but cannot change the text to blue. I found out that I used the entryComponent property in MentionSuggestions to customize the appearance of the suggestionList, if I remove it and use the default (only show name, no email) everything works fine. Is there a way to fix that?
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, Modifier } from 'draft-js'
import Editor from '@draft-js-plugins/editor'
import createMentionPlugin, {
  defaultSuggestionsFilter,
  MentionData,
} from '@draft-js-plugins/mention'
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css'
import '@draft-js-plugins/mention/lib/plugin.css'

const mockUsers = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  name: `User ${index + 1}`,
  email: `user${index + 1}@example.com`,
}))

const mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin({
  mentionTrigger: '@',
  entityMutability: 'IMMUTABLE',
  supportWhitespace: true,
  theme: {
    mention: 'mention',  
  },
  mentionComponent: (mentionProps) => (
    <span className='mention' style={{ color: '#1d9bf0', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
      @{mentionProps.children}
    </span>
  ),
})
const { MentionSuggestions } = mentionPlugin
const plugins = [mentionPlugin]

const CustomEntry = (props) => {
  const { mention, isFocused, onAddMention } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={`mention-suggestion-item ${isFocused ? 'focused' : ''}`}
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onAddMention(mention)
      }}
      style={{
        padding: '8px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      }}
    >
      <strong>{mention.name}</strong>
      <div style={{ fontSize: '12px', color: '#666' }}>{mention.email}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

const DraftMentionEditor: React.FC = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState<EditorState>(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty(),
  )
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState(mockUsers.slice(0, 10))
  const [isSuggestionsOpen, setSuggestionsOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleEditorChange = useCallback((state: EditorState) => {
    setEditorState(state)
  }, [])

  const onOpenChange = useCallback((open: boolean) => {
    setSuggestionsOpen(open)
  }, [])

  const onSearchChange = useCallback(({ value }: { value: string }) => {
    const filteredSuggestions = defaultSuggestionsFilter(value, mockUsers)
    setSuggestions(filteredSuggestions.slice(0, 10))
  }, [])

  const addMention = useCallback(
    (mention: MentionData) => {
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
      const selection = editorState.getSelection()

      // Tạo entity cho mention
      const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
        'MENTION',
        'IMMUTABLE',
        { mention },
      )
      const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey()

      const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
        contentStateWithEntity,
        selection,
        `@${mention.name} `,
        null,
        entityKey,
      )

      let newEditorState = EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        newContentState,
        'insert-characters',
      )

      newEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(
        newEditorState,
        newContentState.getSelectionAfter(),
      )

      setEditorState(newEditorState)
      setSuggestionsOpen(false)  
    },
    [editorState],
  )

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    const content = editorState.getCurrentContent()
    const rawContent = convertToRaw(content)
    console.log('Submitted content:', rawContent)
  }, [editorState])

  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: '600px', margin: 'auto', padding: '20px' }}>
      <div
        style={{
          border: '1px solid #d1d5da',
          borderRadius: '6px',
          padding: '12px',
          minHeight: '100px',
        }}
      >
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
          plugins={plugins}
          placeholder='Type @ to mention someone...'
        />
        <MentionSuggestions
          open={isSuggestionsOpen}
          onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
          onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
          suggestions={suggestions}
          onAddMention={addMention}
          entryComponent={(props) => (
            <CustomEntry {...props} onAddMention={addMention} />
          )}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        style={{
          marginTop: '10px',
          padding: '10px 20px',
          backgroundColor: '#2ea44f',
          color: 'white',
          border: 'none',
          borderRadius: '6px',
          cursor: 'pointer',
          fontWeight: 500,
        }}
      >
        Gửi tin nhắn
      </button>

      <style>{`
        .mention {
          color: #1d9bf0;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        .mention-suggestions-container {
          position: absolute;
          background: white;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          z-index: 1000;
          max-height: 200px;
          overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .mention-suggestion-item {
          padding: 8px;
          cursor: pointer;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        .mention-suggestion-item:hover {
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DraftMentionEditor


This is what I did:
enter image description here
This is what I want:
enter image description here
In suggestion dropdown I want to list multi information (name, email...)
